# sequlize order by only from main query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

how can I order by only from main query ? here is my example.

```
     model
        .findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                status: 'Pending'
            },
            attributes: [
                'id',
                [Sequelize.literal('CAST((SELECT count(*) FROM "table1" WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" ' +
                    ) AS INTEGER) '), 'table1Count']

            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: model2,
                    as: 'model2'
                }
            ],
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,
            order: [
                [Sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN  "table1Count" >= 1 THEN "table1Count" END'), 'DESC','NULLS LAST'],
                ['id', 'ASC']]
        })
```

Genarated query as below.In here I am getting `column "table1Count" does not exist'.

```
 SELECT
  "model".*,
  "model2"."id"   AS "model2.id",
  "model2"."name" AS "model2.name"
FROM (SELECT
        "model"."id",
        CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) AS "table1Count"
      FROM "model" AS "model"
      WHERE "model"."status" = 'Pending'
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN "table1Count" >= 1 **how to avoid order by here**
        THEN "table1Count" END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC
      LIMIT '50'
      OFFSET '0') AS "model" LEFT OUTER JOIN
  "model2" AS "model2" ON "model"."id" = "model2"."modelId"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "table1Count" >= 1
  THEN "table1Count" END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC;
```

How can I order by only from Main query ?

Expected query is as bellow..

```
 SELECT
  "model".*,
  "model2"."id"   AS "model2.id",
  "model2"."name" AS "model2.name"
FROM (SELECT
        "model"."id",
        CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) AS "table1Count"
      FROM "model" AS "model"
      WHERE "model"."status" = 'Pending'
      LIMIT '50'
      OFFSET '0') AS "model" LEFT OUTER JOIN
  "model2" AS "model2" ON "model"."id" = "model2"."modelId"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "table1Count" >= 1
  THEN "table1Count" END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC
```

Just only need order from main/outer query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is not the best answer.

I just add the sub query in the order by

```
SELECT
  "model".*,
  "model2"."id"   AS "model2.id",
  "model2"."name" AS "model2.name"
FROM (SELECT
        "model"."id",
        CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) AS "table1Count"
      FROM "model" AS "model"
      WHERE "model"."status" = 'Pending'
      LIMIT '50'
      OFFSET '0') AS "model" LEFT OUTER JOIN
  "model2" AS "model2" ON "model"."id" = "model2"."modelId"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) >= 1
  THEN CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is `separate : true`, what it will does is run your query separately

```
include: [
    {
        model: model2,
        as: 'model2' ,
        separate : true // <---- Magic is here
    }
],
```

Comment: That will generate query like this `SELECT
        "model"."id",
        CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) AS "table1Count"
      FROM "model" AS "model"
      WHERE "model"."status" = 'Pending'
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN "table1Count" >= 1 **how to avoid order by here**
        THEN "table1Count" END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC
      LIMIT '50'
      OFFSET '0'` but still 'table1Count'  does not exist

Comment: provide `order by` `id` in `include`

Answer (score 0):

In sequelize we have such if:

```
if (
          subQuery
          && Array.isArray(order)
          && order[0]
          && !(order[0] instanceof Association)
          && !(typeof order[0] === 'function' && order[0].prototype instanceof Model)
          && !(typeof order[0].model === 'function' && order[0].model.prototype instanceof Model)
          && !(typeof order[0] === 'string' && model && model.associations !== undefined && model.associations[order[0]])
        ) {
          subQueryOrder.push(this.quote(order, model, '->'));
        }
        mainQueryOrder.push(this.quote(order, model, '->'));
```

So, you should change your order to get `false` in this if.

Comment: `subquery:false` will not generate the sub query.But still  table1Count is not exist

Comment: @Dinesh In `order by` change `"table1Count"` to `model."table1Count"`. Plus don't forget that you may get the problem with `subquery: false` when you have 1:m relation.

Comment: when you add subquery:false ,You will get query like this `SELECT
        "model"."id",
        CAST((SELECT count(*)
              FROM "table1"
              WHERE "table1"."id" = "model"."id" AS INTEGER) AS "table1Count"
      FROM "model" AS "model"
      WHERE "model"."status" = 'Pending'
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN "table1Count" >= 1 **how to avoid order by here**
        THEN "table1Count" END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC
      LIMIT '50'
      OFFSET '0'` 
'

Comment: Even we user query like bellow as you explain still get the error.
` ORDER BY CASE WHEN model."table1Count" >= 1 
        THEN model."table1Count" END DESC NULLS LAST, "model"."id" ASC

Comment: @Dinesh with `subquery: false` you should do as you write below (add the subquery in the order by). In another case (without `subquery: false`), you should add an alias name like: `model."table1Count"`